# Cannot get OL measurement in km/km2 with the map view in EPSG:4326

Tags: openlayers

I am using the Openlayers [mouse](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mouse-position.html) and [measure using vector styles](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure-style.html) examples plus some OL controls (eg. [zoom slider](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/zoomslider.html)) and my map view projection is in EPSG:4326 as follows:

```
const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new LayerGroup({
      title: 'Base',
      fold: 'open',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM(),
          title: 'OSM',
          type: 'base',
          visible: false,
        }),
      ],
        some,more,layers,here,
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      center: [-85, -22],
      zoom: 8,
      minZoom: 8,
      maxZoom: 13,
      extent: [-87, -31, -65, -13],
  }),
});
```

The problem is that my area/distance measurements are being displayed in degrees, which should be expected as my map view is in EPSG:4326 (by default map view is in EPSG:3857 if I am right). Thus, I am reprojecting the geometry's feature while the measurement is made based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313855/converting-openlayers-polygon-to-geojson-with-different-projection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134974/transforming-coordinates-of-feature-in-openlayers) (ie. `const geometry = feature.getGeometry().clone().transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');`), so changing the following relevant piece of code as follows:

```
function styleFunction(feature, segments, drawType, tip) {
  const styles = [];
  //const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
  const geometry = feature.getGeometry().clone().transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');   // <--- change here
  console.log(geometry);
  const type = geometry.getType();
  let point, label, line;
  if (!drawType || drawType === type || type === 'Point') {
    styles.push(style);
    if (type === 'Polygon') {
      point = geometry.getInteriorPoint();
      label = formatArea(geometry);
      line = new LineString(geometry.getCoordinates()[0]);
    } else if (type === 'LineString') {
      point = new Point(geometry.getLastCoordinate());
      label = formatLength(geometry);
      line = geometry;
    }
  }
  if (segments && line) {
    let count = 0;
    line.forEachSegment(function (a, b) {
      const segment = new LineString([a, b]);
      const label = formatLength(segment);
      if (segmentStyles.length - 1 < count) {
        segmentStyles.push(segmentStyle.clone());
      }
      const segmentPoint = new Point(segment.getCoordinateAt(0.5));
      segmentStyles[count].setGeometry(segmentPoint);
      segmentStyles[count].getText().setText(label);
      styles.push(segmentStyles[count]);
      count++;
    });
  }
  if (label) {
    labelStyle.setGeometry(point);
    labelStyle.getText().setText(label);
    styles.push(labelStyle);
  }
  if (
    tip &&
    type === 'Point' &&
    !modify.getOverlay().getSource().getFeatures().length
  ) {
    tipPoint = geometry;
    tipStyle.getText().setText(tip);
    styles.push(tipStyle);
  }
  return styles;
}
```

After doing this change, the console.log information says the following (eg. the area is `1.0006530922462364e-11`):

[image]

Not sure where is the error here, any hints are much appreciated,

OL imports are:

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import TileWMS from 'ol/source/TileWMS.js';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector.js';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector.js';
import Geometry from 'ol/geom/Geometry.js';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON.js';
import MousePosition from 'ol/control/MousePosition.js';
import {toStringHDMS} from 'ol/coordinate.js';
import {createStringXY} from 'ol/coordinate.js';
import {Group as LayerGroup} from 'ol/layer.js';
import {ScaleLine} from 'ol/control.js';
import {FullScreen} from 'ol/control.js';
import {ZoomSlider} from 'ol/control.js';
import {Attribution} from 'ol/control.js';
import LayerSwitcher from 'ol-layerswitcher';
import {BaseLayerOptions, GroupLayerOptions} from 'ol-layerswitcher';
import 'ol-layerswitcher/dist/ol-layerswitcher.css';
import {
import {Draw, Modify} from 'ol/interaction.js';
import {LineString, Point} from 'ol/geom.js';
import {getArea, getLength} from 'ol/sphere.js';
```

**UPDATE #1**

Thanks to @Andrea Giudiceandrea and @Mike I modified my code (eg. the `.transform()` method) to get the metric values as expected (eg. 2759016616.541616 in the image below) but the measurement is not displayed in my map view (ie. tooltip section, for some reason the value label is missing there), not sure why, here the relevant piece of code about the `.getArea()` method:

```
const formatArea = function (polygon) {
  //const area = getArea(polygon);
  const area = getArea(polygon, 'EPSG:3857' );  // change here
  console.log(area);
  let output;
  if (area > 10000) {
    output = Math.round((area / 1000000) * 100) / 100 + ' km\xB2';
  } else {
    output = Math.round(area * 100) / 100 + ' m\xB2';
  }
  return output;
};
```

[image]

Comment: I think the only change you need to make to the example is to specify the view projection as an option in the getArea and getLength call https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html

Comment: @Mike nice to know that there is a projection option there, however, not sure how to use it, my map view dissapeared after using this: `const formatArea = function (polygon) {
  const area = getArea(polygon, options: { projection: 'EPSG:3857' });
console.log(area);
  let output;
  if (area > 10000) {
    output = Math.round((area / 1000000) * 100) / 100 + ' km\xB2';
  } else {
    output = Math.round(area * 100) / 100 + ' m\xB2';
  }
  return output;
};`

Comment: EPSG:3857 is the default option.  If your view uses EPSG:4326 and you use `getArea(polygon, { projection: 'EPSG:4326' })` there should be no need to transform.

Comment: Works now like a champ, thanks @Mike! please add it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Geometry-Geometry.html#transform

```
transform(source, destination)
```

where

> source:   The current projection.
>
> destination: The desired projection.

If you want to transform a geometry object from `EPSG:4326` to `EPSG:3857`:

`transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')`

Comment: you are right, my mistake, thanks for pointing that! however, the value is still not displayed, please see my update above.